# VBA Vlookup with defined name range

Tags: vba, excel

I am having 2 workbooks (Lookup and Destination) and trying to retrieve values from a defined name range in the Lookup workbook.

```
 ......
 Set rng = Range(Cells(15, 3), Cells(863, 12)) 'C15:L863
 wbkLookup.Names.Add Name:="LookupAreaDK", RefersTo:=rng
 ......
 colDest.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & colLookup.Address(False, False) & ", LookupAreaDK ,10,0)"
```

But I've got `#NAME?` as returned values. What is wrong with the syntax? Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: What is colLookup.Address(False, False)? And please check the ": they must be doubled in the macro like colDest.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & colLookup.Address(False, False) & """, LookupAreaDK ,10,0)"

Comment: colLookup.Address(False, False) is currently "AG8". Could you tell me what you mean by "doubled in the macro"?

Comment: formula shown in Excel file with triple quotes of colLookup.Address is: VLOOKUP(" & colLookup.Address(False, False) & "; LookupAreaDK;10;0); while the double quotes give:   =VLOOKUP("AG8"; LookupAreaDK;10;0)

Comment: Ah, I see now. No, you do not need to "escape" the quotation marks here, but please check that the colLookup.Address(False, False) is working. I tested with Range("E1").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & "D1" & ", LookupAreaDK ,3,0)", and it worked alright.

Comment: Thanks, I've got to work a bit more on the colLookup.Address(False, False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to assign the address to the colLookup, or create another variable.
Then, this works:

```
Dim colLookup As String
colLookup = Cells(1, 4).Address
colDest.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & colLookup & ", LookupAreaDK ,3,0)"
```